# RabbitMQ MassTransit Clustering Issue

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

Environment: `RabbitMQ 3.8.14`, `Erlang 23.2`, `Masstrnasit 7.2.2`, `Asp.net core 5.0`  `Windows server 2016`.
I have two nodes  with names `rabbit@rabbitOne` and `rabbit@rabbitTwo` in separate servers.
according by RabbitMQ [official documents](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#:%7E:text=A%20RabbitMQ%20cluster%20is%20a,parameters%20and%20other%20distributed%20state.), I set the same erlang cookie for two nodes. and have joined the `rabbit@rabbitTwo` node to the `rabbit@rabbitOne` node.
 every thing is correct. and I saw two nodes in the RabbitMQ Mangement UI of the *rabbit@rabbitTwo* server. 
 I have been saw all queues that belong to the 'rabbit@rabbitOne'.
I also created some queues with type of [Quorum Queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html).

I configured MassTransit  with following code:

```
x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host(configuration["clusterName"], opt =>
                    {
              //the host set and test with multiple value; cluster name or host Ip port of the rabbit@rabbitOne node.
  
                        opt.UseCluster(cluster =>
                        {
                            var nodes = configuration["Rabbit:Nodes"].Split(";");
                             //nodes set with Ip port. 
                            foreach (var node in nodes)
                            {
                                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node))
                                    continue;

                                cluster.Node(node);
                            }
                        });

                        opt.Username(configuration["Rabbit:UserName"]);
                        opt.Password(configuration["Rabbit:Password"]);
                    });
```

now, I published events to the queues. and they correctly worked.
**the problem**:
I want to `simulate high availability`, for this work, I manually stopped `rabbit@rabbitOne` node. I have bee saw the `down state` for  the `rabbit@rabbitOne` node and all his queues except my Quorum Queues, that they are in the `running state`. 
[image]

 but with this state(rabbit@rabbitOne) MassTransit Bus couldn't connect to  the RabbitMQ. I got the exception: 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'. `connection faild: "rabbitmq://myMlusterName"`.
I know what's mean. But I assume this tips: Despite the `rabbit@rabbitOne` node was down, but `rabbit@rabbitTwo` node with quorum queues must be available!. 
Miss I understnding any thing about RabbitMQ clustering?
I guess, I must be set Host with another value in MassTransit configurations? 
 must be I set a thing in the RabbitMQ config file for discovery nodes?
or another miss understnding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quorum queues require a quorum to be accessible, which means either 2 of 3 nodes, or 3 of 4 nodes, etc. You can't have a quorum queue with only a single node available. It's (N/2)+1. And 2/2+1=2.

It's [right in the documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html).

> Classic HA queues work with a single node, but can potentially result in a split-brain if you don't use pause minority and manually recover the failed nodes.